# How can i make css vertical scrolling animation?

Tags: html, css

I intend to make CSS vertical scrolling infinite animation in WordPress
here is a demo: https://www.silkmaison.com (you can see top header)

How can I achieve it?

Comment: We are not there to do your homework. Or solve your genetic problems for free. If you have a specific question, ask it. But add all detail so we can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches that you may take, here's a possibility with animation and margin-top

```js
let h1s = document.querySelectorAll("h1");
index = -1;
setInterval(function() {
    if (index >= 0) h1s[index].style.display = "none";
    h1s[index = ((index + 1) % h1s.length)].style.display = "block";
}, 2000);
```

```css
h1 {
    animation-name: slidein;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    display: none;
}
@keyframes slidein {
    0% {
        visibility: visible;
        color: blue;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        visibility: visible;
        color: blue;
        margin-top: 280px;
    }
}
div {
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h1>ONE</h1>
<h1>TWO</h1>
<h1>THREE</h1>
</div>
```